# Adapt to all devices with autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, autolayout

I am trying to design a screen like below. I can do this design for several devices for example IPhone 5 and 5S. This means that my application runs properly on IPhone 5 and 5S. But when I try to run it on IPhone 6 or 6S, my design is broken and disrupted. How can I do a common design for all devices.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code here for us to look at?

Comment: I already use Autolayout so I have no code.

Comment: the number of buttons there fix? or it can be more?

Comment: Yes the button number is fix. There will be 11 buttons.

Comment: is the size of all the buttons fixed?

Comment: Yes it is fixed also. But buttons has to get bigger or smaller according to device size. For example, in IPhone 4s and in IPhone 6s pattern ( in other words template, model etc.) of buttons has to be same.

Comment: It'd probably be helpful to hear what exactly is "broken and disrupted" on the 6 and 6s. Also, what strategy are you using for your auto-layout constraints? If you really want your buttons laid out on an ellipse like that, you ought to be able to set up the constraints based on the equation of the ellipse.

Comment: Can you please post a picture of how it is broken? Also maybe a picture of your constraints in storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that gives an CGPoint offset from the center, for a given index

```
func offset(forIndex index: Int) -> CGPoint {
  let part = M_PI / 11.0
  let phi = part * Double(index)
  let x = Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width) * sin(phi)
  let y = Double(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height) * cos(phi)
  print("----")
  print("index \(index)")
  print("x \(x)")
  print("y \(y)")

  return CGPoint(x: CGFloat(x), y: CGFloat(y))
}
```

With this function, you can position your button accordingly

Comment: I prefer this strategy over using auto-layout for something this custom.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's a pattern that I've used before:

[image]

The grey bars are just UIViews which expand and shrink to keep all of the buttons spaced equally on different screen. In your actual design, these would be transparent. Each of those views has a constraint to make them the same height - this keeps the space between the buttons equal, regardless of the vertical size of the screen.

The other constraints are that the middle button is constrained to be vertically centered, and that each of the buttons has an increasing trailing space to the containing view. Each button is *also* constrained to have 0 points of spacing to the view above and below.

When you run this on a small screen, the spacers will shrink, and on a bigger screen, they'll grow. On larger screens, you should also get larger buttons, if they're set to use the intrinsic size.

This doesn't preserve the shape of the ellipse, but you could make the x coordinate of the button proportional to the width of the screen to do that, I guess. Depends on what your goals are for the overall look.